# Cropping a photo with PHP gets stretched

Tags: php, image, image-processing, thumbnails

I'm trying to resize and crop a picture.

The picture can be landscape or portrait oriented but I want the thumbnail to be 250x250 and not stretched (crop the sides or the top/bottom but keep most of the image intact in the new size, cropped to square - kinda like wordpress's thumbnails).

This is my function, it's the right size but its stretching the pictures...

What am i doing wrong?

```
function make_thumb($src, $dest, $desired_width, $ext) {

    if ($ext == 'jpg' || $ext == 'jpeg') {
            $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);      
    }
    if ($ext == 'png') {
            $source_image = imagecreatefrompng($src);       
    }
    if ($ext == 'gif') {
            $source_image = imagecreatefromgif($src);       
    }   

    /* read the source image */
    $width = imagesx($source_image);
    $height = imagesy($source_image);

/* find the "desired height" of this thumbnail, relative to the desired width  */
    $desired_height = floor($height * ($desired_width / $width));
    $desired_height = 250;

    /* create a new, "virtual" image */
    $virtual_image = imagecreatetruecolor($desired_width, $desired_height);

    /* copy source image at a resized size */
    imagecopyresampled($virtual_image, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $desired_width, $desired_height, $width, $height);

    /* create the physical thumbnail image to its destination */

    if ($ext == 'jpg' || $ext == 'jpeg') {
            imagejpeg($virtual_image, $dest);       
    }
    if ($ext == 'png') {
            imagepng($virtual_image, $dest);        
    }
    if ($ext == 'gif') {
            imagegif($virtual_image, $dest);        
    }   
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe use `imagecopy` for cropping once you resize the image?

Comment: @Tom No, if you distort the image in your resize copying it is not likely to fix anything is it.

Comment: @RiggsFolly you're right - I was assuming the resize would be done to the correct proportions. Since `imagecopyresampled` can also be used for cropping then using `imagecopy` is a redundant step if you don't want to keep the resided image but only the cropped thumbnail. We don't know that, however.

Answer (score 1):

Think about what you are saying for a second.

If you change the width of an image and do not change the height in exactly the same proportion as you have the width, the image is always going to get distorted.

You have the code to do it properly, without distortion, although I have not actually tested the calc is correct and then you override that calculation with the arbitrary height of 250. Hence you get a distortion.

Comment out this line and it will probably stop the distortion

```
$desired_height = 250;
```

So if you know you always want an image that is 250 height, change the calulation to calulate the proportionate new width rather than passing it in as a parameter.

```
function make_thumb($src, $dest, $desired_height = 250, $ext) {

    if ($ext == 'jpg' || $ext == 'jpeg') { $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);  }
    if ($ext == 'png') { $source_image = imagecreatefrompng($src); }
    if ($ext == 'gif') { $source_image = imagecreatefromgif($src); }   

    /* read the source image */
    $width = imagesx($source_image);
    $height = imagesy($source_image);

    /* calc the new width */
    $desired_width = floor($width * ($desired_height / $height));

    /* create a new, "virtual" image */
    $virtual_image = imagecreatetruecolor($desired_width, $desired_height);

    /* copy source image at a resized size */
    imagecopyresampled($virtual_image, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $desired_width, $desired_height, $width, $height);

    /* create the physical thumbnail image to its destination */

    if ($ext == 'jpg' || $ext == 'jpeg') { imagejpeg($virtual_image, $dest); }
    if ($ext == 'png') { imagepng($virtual_image, $dest); }
    if ($ext == 'gif') { imagegif($virtual_image, $dest); }   
}
```

Of course the width will vary a bit depending on the actual size of the original image. But you have to let that happen if you want to stop the distortion.

Comment: Isn't there a way to set it both to 250 by 250 and not compromise on one?

Comment: Only if the original picture size had the Width and Height the same eg a square 1000 x 1000, but photos dont usually come square. You could crop it from its actual size to a square and then reduce it to 250 x 250 but because PHP has no eyes you would not be sure you were getting the good bit of the picture.